# Getting the length of a linked list

Tags: c, list

```
typedef struct _node *Node;
typedef struct _list *List;

typedef struct _list {
    Node head;
} list;

typedef struct _node {
    int value;
    Node next;
} node;

int listLength (List l);

int ListLength (List l) {

    /* Insert code here */ 

    return result; //replace this
}
```

Hey, I'm new to linked lists and I'm unsure how to check the length of the list. I'm meant to create a function that does that but I'm unsure how the list can be moved if it only contains (Node head) and not and (Node next).

Comment: A `Node` is a pointer to a `_node`, and an `_node` contains a `Node` called `next` in it. So each `Node` lets you find the next `Node`. (IMO, this use of typedefs is awful. The most important thing to understand about a `Node` is that it's a pointer to something, and you've obscured that.)

Comment: When you insert nodes, you have the last `node->next = NULL;` correct? Why not `node *tmp = l;` and `while (tmp != NULL) { /* count your nodes */; tmp = tmp->next; }`?

Comment: Hey everyone, it's an exercise question so I have to use the format given to me.

Comment: "I'm meant to create a function that does that but I'm unsure how the list can be moved if it only contains (Node head) and not and (Node next)." --> Post the code that handled the `Node next` case.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
int listLength (List l) {
    int len = 0;
    Node n = l->head;
    while(n != NULL){
        len++;
        n = n->next;
    }
    return len;
}
```

When you insert an element you have to set its next to NULL!

```
Node createNode(int val){
    Node n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->value = val;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

void add(int val, List l){
    if(l->head == NULL){
        l->head = createNode(val);
    } else {
        Node n = l->head;
        while(n->next != NULL){
            n = n->next;
        }
        n->next = createNode(val);
    }
}
```

For malloc you have to include stdlib `#include<stdlib.h>`